# LARAVEL: build a next/previous navigation links

Tags: php, laravel

In order to learn to use LARAVEL I have built a WebApp for myself to manage all my films collection (over 350 films) and I have two questions:
I have built a navigation function that reads the slug from the next and previous film in the Database and built the links that allows navigating to the next and previous film in the front end. It works for all films but since the first film has not a valid “previous” film and the last one has not a valid “next” film, the app brakes.
I would like to know how to build the two possible scenarios:

- How could I make that the links works in a “circular way”, meaning that in the case of the last film, the “NEXT link” points to the first film and in the case of the first film details page, the PREVIOUS link point to the last?
- How could I make that the First film does not have a PREVIOUS link and the last film does not have a NEXT link?
  These solutions should work regardless the order in which the films appear in the list. At the moment the list could be ordered by title, name, country, language, age classification, language and genre. In the other hand, I am adding films constantly, so the last and first movies are always changing.

Here is the function in the controller:

```
$prev = $film->id - 1;
        $film_prev = DB::table('films')
                    ->select('films.*')
                    ->where('films.id', '=', $prev)->first();  

$next = $film->id + 1;  
        $film_next = DB::table('films')
                    ->select('films.*')
```

I am building it just to learn but, is there any plugin or ready solution for that topic?

Comment: I am not sure assuming a continuous sequence of ids is the right thing, but in case it's fine for you could always do try {} and change first() into firstOrFail() catching and handling the exception properly...
And BTW I am not sure controller is the right place for this...

Comment: @jakubwrona, which is the right place to build and host such functionality? the View (html)?

Comment: I would rather think about a Film class with public function prev() and public function next() in it.

Comment: Laravel has pretty functional pagination capabilities (https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/pagination).  Is there a reason you are trying to manually rebuild this functionality?  I have never tried it with a page size of 1, but I don't see any reason why it would not work.

Comment: @JodyBoucher, as I stated I am learning Laravel. Since this is not a production project (I am my client), I decided to give the pagination a try to exercise my skills. Thanks for the link